# How can I change it into the array?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, contour, surface

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


x = np.linspace(-1,1,100)
y = 2 * x + 3 + np.random.rand(len(x))
x1,x2=np.meshgrid(x,y)

F = (x1 - 2) ** 2 + 2 * (x2 - 3) ** 2
fig=plt.figure()
surf = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection='3d')
surf.plot_surface(x1,x2,F)
surf.contour(x1,x2,F,20)

fig, surf=plt.subplots()
plt.contour(x1, x2, F,20)
```

The surface plot is a bit weird because the contour is not in the full.

[image: This is the output]

Why the contour plot is in half?

Answer (score 1):

It is not in half. x goes from -1 to 1, as you have created it.
And y, being (ignoring some noise) 2x+3, goes from 1 to 5. To 6 because of the noise.

So, sure, if x was from -1 to 5, you would see circle countour, since F minimum is at (2,3). You don't see the minimum because it is not in the range you have chosen.

I am not sure neither of why you add this random to y. Since x granularity is 0.01, and therefore y 0.02, that noise is way bigger than the difference between successive values. And because of that your meshgrid is going back and forth to random points. Neither `plot_surface` nor `contour` are meant to be used with random (x,y) points.
Plus, it doesn't change the function you are studying. It just mess up the drawing. Since after all, x and y are just parameters here.
It just impacts randomly the points were you "measure" F, not F itself. If `plot_surface` was able to handle this, with this density of points, we would barely notice. Or if you were just using a 3d scatter plot. It just mess up the drawing because of the inability of contour and `draw_surface` to handle unordered mesh.

See same contour without the random
[image]

At last, I don't understand why you specify `y` that way. It would make sense if the idea was to have a random `x` and then build a correlated `y`. But in this context, where you don't use `x` or `y`, except to build a meshgrid, your y is simply the same thing as `np.linspace(1, 5, 100) + np.random.rand(100)`. If your question was different, I would ignore this and conclude that you have some reason not related to the question, that makes sense outside the minimal example shown.

But your question suggest that you are struggling to have a grid that contains the center (2,3). So, why not just

```py
x=np.linspace(0,4,100) 
y=np.linspace(1,5,100) # So just -2 to +2 around center for x and y
```

And you have it centered around F minimum
[image]

Comment: alright, thankyou. Then the y had rand because i want to random to have the uniform distribution